# I need to detect when objects within a string aren't in the right format and then modify them inline using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I've got multiple stored procedures that need to be formatted to some exact specifications. If "dbo" is detected, then the words connected to it need to be bracketed and lowercase. For example,

```
1 SELECT  c.COLA,
2    c.COLB,
3    c.COLC
4 FROM database.dbo.table1 c
5 LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Table2] cs ON cs.sourceid = c.sourceid
6 LEFT JOIN dbo.FunctionName1('Status', 'N/A') AS vvc ON c.STATUS = vvc.STATUS
7 WHERE c.val <> 'Y'
```

would become

```
1 SELECT  c.COLA,
2    c.COLB,
3    c.COLC
4 FROM [database].[dbo].[table1] c
5 LEFT JOIN [database].[dbo].[table2] cs ON cs.sourceid = c.sourceid
6 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[functionname1]('Status', 'N/A') AS vvc ON c.STATUS = vvc.STATUS
7 WHERE c.val <> 'Y'
```

The from on line 4 was "database.dbo.table1". Brackets need to be added around each word connected to the dbo on each side of the periods, but not around the FROM or the c.

In line 5 "[Database].[dbo].[Table2]" there are already brackets but the whole thing needs to be lowercase.

In line 6 "dbo.FunctionName1('Status', 'N/A')" dbo needs brackets. The function name needs to be lowercase and it also needs brackets added that don't interfere with the parenthesis.

I've been having to go through and do the change line by line manually. If there was a way to automate it, that'd be lovely.

Comment: If you want two problems, use a RegEx.

Comment: It's known as *delimiting* object names. SQL Server doesn't require objects to be delimited except if the name is also a reserved keyword; however what you require can be done by various code formatters, for example SQLPrompt can lower-case object names and delimit object names. Alternatively you could script out the procedure text and parse it yourself - quite a tricky process but maybe worth it of you have hundreds or thousands to edit, if it's 10 then just edit them.

Comment: I have enough to edit that something automated where I could pass the existing string and get back a properly formatted one would be great.

Comment: I'd love to know what you are doing that *requires* it to be lowercase. Are you on a case-sensitive server?

Comment: [SQL formatter tools](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-formatter-tools/)

Comment: @Charlieface Just standards the db team has asked of us. The table titles themselves aren't even lowercase nor is SQL case sensitive. It is what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like this to convert a stored procedure to the required format:

```
    private string ConvertProcedure(string procedure)
    {
        // split each procedure into lines, words, wordparts separated by . or ( 
        var lines = procedure.Split(Environment.NewLine);
        var newProcedure = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            var words = line.Split(' ');
            foreach(var word in words)
            {
                // check for functions
                var wordsAndFunctionPartSeparated = word.Split("(");
                bool isSplitByParenthesis = false;

                foreach (var wordPart in wordsAndFunctionPartSeparated)
                {
                    var tableInformation = wordPart.Split('.');
                    var newWordPart = wordPart;

                    // Only change when it contains dbo
                    if (tableInformation.Any(ti => ti.ToLower() == "dbo" || ti.ToLower() == "[dbo]"))
                    {

                        newWordPart = wordPart.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
                        newWordPart = $"[{newWordPart.Replace(".", "].[")}]";
                    }

                    // Add the ( when it is required.
                    if (isSplitByParenthesis)
                    {
                        newProcedure.Append("(");
                    }
                    newProcedure.Append(newWordPart);
                    isSplitByParenthesis = true;
                }

                newProcedure.Append($" ");
            }

            newProcedure.AppendLine();
        }

        return newProcedure.ToString();
    }
```